# Deleting Strings on the Heap Created from Char[] one the Heap in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stdstring

I have a fairly simple question that I cannot seem to find an answer for relating to C++ std::string and how it is instantiated with new.  Now, I am well aware that any pointer returned from new should be subsequently deleted to prevent memory leak.  My question comes from what happens when an existing pointer is subsequently used to instantiate a new string object.  Please consider the following simplified example:

```
char* foo() {
    char* ptr;

    ptr = new char[ARBITRARY_VALUE];
    ...
    ptr = strncpy("some null terminated string", ARBITRARY_VALUE)
    ...
    return ptr;
}

int main() {

    char* buf;
    std::string myStr;

    buf = foo();
    myStr = new std::string(buf);

    ...do stuff

    delete myStr;
    delete buf;         //Is this necessary?
    return 0;
}
```

**My question is simple: does deleting myStr also free the underlying memory used by buf or does buf need to be freed manually as well?**  If buf has to be freed manually, what happens in the case of anonymous parameters?  As in:

```
myStr = new std::string(foo());
```

My suspicion is that the underlying implementation of std::string only maintains a pointer to the character buffer and, upon destruction, frees **that** pointer but I am not certain and my C++ is rusty at best.

Bonus question:  How would this change if the class in question were something other than std::string?  I assume that for any user created class, an explicit destructor must be provided by the implementer but what about the various other standard classes?  Is it safe to assume that deletion of the parent object will always be sufficient to fully destruct an object (I try to pick my words carefully here; I know there are cases where it is desirable to not free the memory pointed to by an object, but that is beyond the scope of this question)?

Comment: `myStr = new std::string(buf);` is not valid code. Unless you've made a typo and `myStr` is `std::string*`.

Comment: Please read this and live by it: http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1

Comment: And yes, you need to delete `buf`, because `std::string` takes a copy of the data that's pointed by it, the original memory is still there. You'd do it with `delete[] buf;`, though.

Comment: In the case of `myStr = new std::string(foo());` memory is leaked.

Comment: Please never(!) return an allocated pointer. unless it is an allocator function.

Comment: I see.  And, yeah, I really didn't like the allocated pointer thing.  I had been looking around online and it is amazing how many people are advocating it, though.  In this case, would the best way be to simply wrap the data directly into a std::string, thereby saving myself a pointless copy operation as well as pointer headaches?  I apologize if this seems really simple, but it has been quite a few years since I have worked in C++.  It is amazing how much you forget when you have to work in managed frameworks for you job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` may be initialized from a C style null-terminated string (`const char *`). There is no way for `std::string` to know if you need that `const char *` `free()`d, `delete[]()`d or neither, and as already stated it won't.

Use smart-pointers to automatically delete dynamically allocated objects. There are a few different of these, each specialized for particular purposes. Have a look at `scoped_ptr`, `auto_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. Your project will probably have constraints on which smart pointers you get to use.

In the context of C++ there is never a reason to hold strings in manually declared char arrays, `std::string` is much safer to use.